# boost::spirit - parsing AST style from randomly placed entries

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have this data in my file:

```
#TITLE:Destiny;
#SUBTITLE:;
#ARTIST:Smiley;
#BACKGROUND:bg.png;
#SAMPLESTART:43.960;
#SAMPLELENGTH:12.000;
```

I want to parse it using AST into a structure like this:

```
struct data {
   std::string title, subtitle, artist, background;
   double samplestart, samplelength;
};
```

Note: the entries in the file may appear in any order.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
struct prs : qi::symbols< char, qi::parser<...> > {
   prs() {
     add
       ("TITLE", link_to_some_str_parser)
       ("SAMPLESTART", link_to_some_dbl_parser);
   }
};
```

And then use it to get to the correct parser in runtime probably using the [] syntax to store the parsed result into some variable.

Now the main question. Would this even compile? Can qi::symbols be used that way and does that make any sense?
How would you do it otherwise?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to utilize the permutation parser (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/permutation.html)), which allows to match a bunch of alternatives in any sequence.

Comment: Why do you think it does not work with AST's? It should work just fine.

Comment: I can't see any way to use unordered entries together with AST and my struct. am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: If you adapt your struct (using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT) it will be filled by the permutation parser. The sequence of elements in the struct adaptation must match the sequence of components in the permutation parser.